# Can I overlay HTML on a Unity window?

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a website that has rich content displayed in a Unity window. However, this Unity window sits under a navigation menu that has drop-downs, and drop-down menus are going behind the Unity window.

With Flash, this was easily solved by setting the `wmode` property to `transparent`. Is there a similar solution with Unity, or a different solution entirely that works and allows me to place standard HTML over the top of Unity windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some related posts on unity forums

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/22270-Unity-Flash-Div-issue-in-Browser

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10599/does-unity-have-an-embed-parameter-equivalent-to-f.html

The answer: there isn't a way to set some equivalent of the flash `wmode=transparent` but there is a workaround with setting the css `visibility:hidden` (or resizing to `width:1px` & `height:1px`)

So, kind of a hack, but you could set the menu's `hover` event to change `visibility` of the unity window as a workaround.

Comment: Hi, mdmullinax. I don't actually want to hide the Unity window; merely I just want any drop-down menus to appear on top of the Unity window should a user hover over them.

Comment: @Martin, hiding is certainly not ideal, I only offered that as a workaround, there doesn't appear to be a way to have a menu show on top because the Unity window doesn't currently have the option. From one of the posts I linked: `Unity content is rendered on top of everything else by the user's graphics card, which makes it impossible for any other web page elements to render on top of it`

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but this might help someone.
I can get HTML to display over the Unity window in Safari, Chrome, Firefox on my Mac and Windows IE 10 & 11 with a div. I can get it to always display with an iFrame in all windows. The trick with the iFrame is not all browsers support transparent iFrame, so sometimes you will see the iFrame, but not transparent. IE 8 does not support transparency at all and if its set to be on, then the iFrame will not display above the Unity screen.

DIV:
I basically float a DIV over the unity content. Content can be either plain HTML or Flash. Opacity seems to help make it work.
My situation is we have a menu that needs to display over the top part of the Unity window. Note that Unity is NOT in full screen mode, but sits in a Div. Maybe this is why I can do it??
Anyway- the code looks something like this:

```
<div>
   <div><unity object></div>
   <div style="position:absolute; opacity:.9">html or flash content</div>
</div>
```

The iFrame approach works fine for content that is always the same size, but if you have something like a combobox, then its an issue because the window needs to first resize the height to show the drop down, and then the iFrame background will cover all the content.  A hack, is to open a SECOND iframe with the combobox. Sucks, but that is the way I had to do it..

hth-
Dustin

Comment: What about IE 8 & 9? Did you check all browser versions (e.g. FireFox 3.6 - 27, Safari 5+, Chrome 5 - 32, Opera 12 - 19, etc)??

Comment: you can check an example I put up on my blog that shows different images, iFrames, and divs overlayed. The different browsers behave differently with regard to opacity and layering. :  http://litebyte.net/blog/how-to-display-html-over-a-unity-3d-web-app/